# modelling smooth square wave function

Tags: functions, trigonometry, approximation, transformation, mathematical-modeling

I would like to model a smooth square wave function (see graph) but be able to control the amount of smoothness from fairly soft as shown to quite hard.

But I want to control the amount of smoothness using a simple function so the more the graph goes to a crest or peak the more compressed it becomes depending on some parameter that I can adjust.

I thought something sine logarithmic as that tends to compress but could not get that to work. I also want to avoid such things as the sgn function or Fourier series.

[image: clipped sine wave]
[image]

Comment: You could try $(\sin x)^{\frac{1}{2n+1}}$ for $n\ge 0$.

Comment: @Tavish that would require sgn function the work in all quadrants.

Comment: This is how it looks https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xytdzyqpfj

Comment: $y(t)=\mathrm{tanh}(A\sin(2\pi ft))$.  Really crank up $A$ if you want very sharp/compressed.

Comment: @Andy Walls I think that'll do nicely thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can obtain a $1$- parameter smooth approximation starting from the approximation for the sign function, i.e:

$$\sin x /\sqrt{\sin^2 x +\varepsilon ^2} \quad |\; \varepsilon \to 0$$

example

[image: sin_approx_1]

Comment: Nice. To make sure it hits `1` and `-1`, you could multiply the whole equation by $\sqrt{1 +\varepsilon ^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

A generic method for drawing a controllable "smoothed" version of a function that is sharp:

1. Generate the "sharp" function as a time series $S=\{s_0,s_1,\cdots\}$
2. Convolve $S$ with a smoothing kernel, e.g. $[{1 \over 4},{1\over 2},{1\over4}]$
3. If it is not smooth enough, convolve again.

Playing with more sophisticated kernels will give you more freedom and control.