# Fitting function with crossing behaviour

Tags: functions, asymptotics, interpolation

I am looking for a function depending from one parameter, let's call it $\alpha$, to best fit the following data. However other parameters if needed can be added.
[image]

The data show two asymptotes, for $x\rightarrow0$, $y \rightarrow1$ and for $x\rightarrow \infty$, $y \rightarrow x^{-0.5}$. But if the blue curve was obtained for $\alpha_1$ and the orange curve for $\alpha_2$, with $\alpha_2>\alpha_1$, then the $\alpha_2$-curve leaves the symptote $1$ earlier than the $\alpha_1$curve, but it reaches the $x^{-0.5}$-asymptote quicker, then the two curves need to cross at a given point. Increasing the value of $\alpha$ to $\alpha_3>\alpha_2$, the relative curve in green leaves the asymptote $1$ even earlier that the $\alpha_2$-curve, but it goes quicker the asymptote $x^{-0.5}$, so that it will cross firstly the $\alpha_1$-curve and then the $\alpha_2$-curve. And so on incresing $\alpha$. I hope that this behaviour is visible in the image, even if the curves are not well developed in all their branches. On the other side decreasing $\alpha$ the curves show a saturation effect, because they tend to stack on a limiting curve.
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: $1 \over 1 + a \sqrt x$?

Comment: @user619894, unfortunately there is no crossing varying `a` for this function, just a "monotonic" behavior of the curves.

Comment: does this help: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3963472/617446

Comment: @user619894, yes it could maybe, could you just expand a bit that answer, I can't really understand it, shame on me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Write $F(x)=min(1, {1\over \sqrt x})$. This is the "asymptotic" target function. We are looking for a parametric smoothing $f(x,\alpha)$ so that when $\alpha \rightarrow 0$ we recover $F(x)$. In order to smooth $F$ we can consider a convolution of $F$ with a smoothing kernel.
For example, the Gaussian gives:

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lgqrlohz9s

[image]

Comment: thank you, I am trying to study your interesting solution. I'll be soon back, hopefully, :)

Comment: But the convolution that you propose is higher than the right asymptotte, $x^{-0.5}$, and this is not allowed; I did no specify this however, excuse me. Probably there is a correction to do.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:
Apply a softmin to $min(1, {1\over \sqrt x})$

Note that $softmin(a,b)$ can be constructed from a softmax via ${1 \over softmax({1\over a}, {1\over b})}$
So for example,using the $p$ norm as the soft max:
$M_p(a,b)=(a^p + b^p)^{1\over  p}$
we can write
$S_p(1,{1\over \sqrt x})=(1+x^-{p\over 2})^{-{1\over p}}$

With $p$ the smoothing parmeter. It is also easier to implement than the convolution:

[image: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/axyjipxkv1]

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much. However, there is no crossing varying $p$ even if this function works really well and it is easy to implement.

Comment: I thought that the convolution solution wasn't suitable  _because_ there was a crossing?

Comment: Excuse me, I did not understand your last comment.

Comment: Then, if this is a norm, the two asymptotes are like the two components of a vector. An increasing $p$ the norm increases? And the $S_p$ is more close to the two asymptotes? I am used to cosider a norm a distance.
(Probably there is an error: $S_p=(1+x^{p/2})^{-1/p}$)

Comment: Refer to the image for the effect of $p$. basically $p\rightarrow \infty$ selects the minimal value. As for you other comment, can you please explain what you mean by "there is not crossing varying p ..."?

Comment: Thank you! Well, as I tried to explain in my question, after the figure, the curves cross each other, i.e. they intercept each other at given points. For eample, curve 1 and 2 cross at about $x=3$. But the fitting you proposed gives curves that never cross, never intercept each other.

Comment: So to summarize: a parametric smoothing that is always below the asymptote yet as a function of the parameters crosses some curves with other parameters? Sounds very tailored.

Comment: Yes, it seems quite difficult, probably more paramenters are needed. The fitting has to complain to the two asymptotes.